# Doing partial search with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to get Mongoose to return results in a query when I only give a *partial* query. For example: I have a 'Company' schema that lists a bunch of companies. A document example:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57aabeb80057405968de1539"),
"companyName" : "Vandelay Industries",
"owner" : "Ary Vandelay",
"inception" : 2012,
"__v" : 1
}
```

So if I do a search query like this:

```
Company.findOne(
    { companyName: Vandelay Industries }, function (err, company) {
        if (company) {
            //do stuff
        }
    });
```

This will produce the document. But If I do the following, I won't get a result:

```
Company.findOne(
    { companyName: Vandelay }, function (err, company) {
        if (company) {
            //do stuff
        }
    });
```

I would like to be able to do these sorts of partial searches and still get a result. Is there any way to do that with Mongoose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve this you can use a regex search to get the required result.

```
var searchKey = new RegExp('Vandelay', 'i')
Company.findOne({ companyName: searchKey }, function (err, company) {
    if (company) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814456/how-to-get-all-the-values-that-contains-part-of-a-string-using-mongoose-find) stackoverflow post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `query` to get result on specific value

```
Company.findOne({"companyName": /Vandelay/},function(err,company){
    if(!err){
        console.log(company);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get result faster you should use indexing ref https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/.

```
db.Company.createIndex( { companyName: "text" } )
```

then you can search

```
   db.Company.find( { $text: { $search: "company name" } } )
```

But this only support full word search not partial, so adding an extra line to this will help

```
   db.Company.find({ $or: [
            { $text: { $search: query } },
             { companyName: { $regex: '^' + 'copmany name'} }
          ]}
```

This will help you search the results faster than normal

Answer (score -1):

Are you doing a fulltext search? If you do that:

```
TagGroup.find({
    $text: {
        $search: text
    }
}, {
    score: {
        $meta: "textScore"
    }
}).sort({
    score: {
        $meta: 'textScore'
    }
})
```

Try that code below. Also you need create a index on that schema

```
TagGroupSchema.index({
    "$**": "text"
});
```

[Here is the document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#create-text-index)

You can use elasticsearch to do that either, when the documents grows, you should consider this way.